# How to tell if web visitor is a robot

Tags: asp-classic, bots, server-variables

On an ASP website, is there a way to tell whether a visitor is a robot?

I'm thinking there might be a parameter in the `ServerVariables` collection that could be used, in a similar way to `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and `REMOTE_ADDR` can be used to get the visitor's IP addresses.

Searches on Google have so far yieled few leads.

Comment: Not sure how you will use it, but you could require interaction, like a CAPTCHA to check.  That is what they are for, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to try

```
HTTP_USER_AGENT
```

Comment: Not that dissimilar to what we have to do with robot files to disallow certain bot actions on a asp-classic website. He wanted a way to check for a bot, gonna need a list for the ones he cares about with that suggestion.. but like I said, its just my suggestion

Comment: @Pricey thanks, I was afraid I might have to build a list but this gets me started.

Comment: I would suggest something bit smarter: as mentioned [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14365390/447356), most bots will try to access "robots.txt" so you can have it run server side (by configuring .txt extension to be parsed by asp.dll assuming you don't have real text files) then detect the HTTP_USER_AGENT of the visitor (who can be assumed to be a bot) and store it somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

There is no bullet-proof method because headers and origins can be spoofed.

Comment: I'm not looking for bullet-proof. Just trying to reduce noise I'm getting in some custom reports.

Comment: You analytics tools should be able to filter out search engine bot traffic.

Comment: @greener most bots will happily spoof the user agent.

Answer (score 1):

if a visitor access robots.txt  it's most likely a spider.
IF there is nothing in the host or user-agent information or there is no referring URL or IP address changes within a visit or
if the log lines appear together in an uninterrupted block in the log file then it's most likely robot traffic.

thanks

Comment: This seems more logical than a user agent black/white list